# SQL Get the total value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I used SQL Server 2005, and I want to get the total value of the 1 invoice

Current Output:

```
Invoice     price    
-------------------
1234       2000    
1234       2500     
9012        3000       
3456        1000
```

but my select field (this is for the price) is already long and i don't know know how to add the sum on it,

```
   RIGHT('000000000000'+ convert(varchar,cast(A.IVC_ForeignGrossAmt as decimal(9,2))),13) as IVC_ForeignGross,
```

The expected output should be :

```
Invoice     price   
-------------------
1234       4500        
1234       4500       
9012        3000       
3456        1000
```

Comment: What is the type of IVC_ForeignGrossAmt, is it not a decimal in the table?

Comment: @Captain16 do you need duplicate invoice ??

Comment: Not sure why you are using this line?  `RIGHT('000000000000'+ convert(varchar,cast(A.IVC_ForeignGrossAmt as decimal(9,2))),13) as IVC_ForeignGross,`

Comment: @bonCodigo I guess he needs leading 0s always before the numbers

Comment: because i'm importing the output to text file and the output that required is '0000002896.15'

Comment: 0000002896.15 is not reflected in "expected output"

Answer (score 2):

Use a correlated subquery, like so:

```
SELECT
  Invoice,
  (SELECT SUM(t2.price)
   FROM table1 t2
   WHERE t1.invoice = t2.invoice) price           
FROM Table1 t1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c81ac/1)

This will give you:

```
| INVOICE | PRICE |
-------------------
|    1234 |  4500 |
|    1234 |  4500 |
|    9012 |  3000 |
|    3456 |  1000 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `SUM-OVER` with `PARTITION BY Invoice` (which is similar to a `Group By`):

```
SELECT
   Invoice, SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice) AS price   
FROM 
   dbo.Table
```

(however, not sure about the `RIGHT('000000000000...` part of your question)

Comment: how can I add the sum-over partition by in my select field?

Comment: @Captain16: But your question is a bit confusing. `IVC_ForeignGross` is not `price` and your expected output does also not have leading zeros like `0000002896.15`. Can you clarify your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the out put meant to be,

```
Invoice     price   
-------------------
1234       4500             
9012        3000       
3456        1000
```

You may try

```
SELECT INVOICE.ID, SUM(PRICE) FROM INVOICE
GROUP BY INVOICE.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Invoice, SUM(price) FROM table1 GROUP BY Invoice;
```

Comment: captain16 required the duplicate invoice. This will not give the duplicate

Comment: @syedmohsin *`duplicate invoice`*?

Comment: may be, but i don't think so it's good idea to show same thing in next row or may be he/she would be confuse

Comment: It definitely doesn't look like a duplicate invoice, it's the total for `id 1234 4500 = 2000 + 2500`...

Comment: @bonCodigo, and i think he/she must be confused, he/she just need to calculate the sum of same invoice.

Comment: I know that is the total. But the invoice number is duplicate.

Comment: I agree with both of you. I would personally use this record once.  My first reaction was the the above query.

Comment: @var___ yes i want to to get the total of the same invoice. but my problem is how i will add in my select field that i specified.

Comment: actually there are 2 or 3 lines in 1 invoice number because in the database there are no grand total so i need to sum it thru query.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the `SUM` of the the prices based on a `GROUP BY` on the Invoice, and format the price as you wanted.

```
SELECT A.Invoice, 
RIGHT('000000000000'+ convert(varchar,cast(SUM(A.IVC_ForeignGrossAmt)
as decimal(9,2))),13) as IVC_ForeignGross 
FROM yourTable A
GROUP BY Invoice;
```